# Three.js debug GLTF model size and position

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three.js and I want to render a simple model in a GLTF (or glb) format. I've downloaded two models from Sketchfab:

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/head-of-michelangelos-david-optimised-d29af50360624e5e9b1855666475380d

https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/snake-statue-794b77a3e4654a669cf259d20dc89ec7

The first model I was using (the david bust) was not showing and I couldn't figure out why, so I tried another one (the snake). The code below renders it perfectly. right in the center of the screen.

I've tried changing the scale and position for the david bust, but it is nowhere to be seen. I do not know how to debug or figure out why it wouldn't show. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the file. It loads in and shows in the `Scene` object in the console.

How can I debug this and have the David bust display right in the center of the screen just like the snake does?

Here is a mostly boilerplate code that I'm using:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

camera.position.z = 5;

const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 2);
directionalLight.position.set(0,0,5);
scene.add( directionalLight );


const loader = new GLTFLoader();

let model;

loader.load( 'assets/models/snake/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

    var loadedModel = gltf.scene;
    loadedModel.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
    loadedModel.position.set(0,-2,0);
   
    scene.add( loadedModel );
    console.log(scene);
    
    model = loadedModel;

}, function(xhr) {
    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

}, 

undefined, function ( error ) {

    console.error( error );

} );


function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

      if (model) model.rotation.y += 0.005;

    renderer.render( scene, camera  );
  

}
animate();


window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize(){

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}
```

EDIT: if i play around with the position in the console. i see a tiny tiny white dot that moves around. but scaling up and down makes its basically disappear.

Comment: Did you try zooming out / scaling down? When viewing the models on the scetchfab site, the snake loads small and zooms in, but the bust does not. This suggests to me that the snake model is much smaller.

Comment: yea, i've added orbit controls too. i've zoomed and out and it's nowhere to be found. other models at least show up after zooming out far enough. im stumped

Comment: add a temp ambientLight to the scene, maybe the directionalLight isn't pointing at the model.

Comment: thanks for the tip! I was able to use the light at a high intensity to basically play with the x,y,z position for an hour and move it to the center of the screen. i have no idea why this model in particular was so much trouble. the position is at `122,106,602` and scale at `3.5`. i don't get why position cant be around `0,0,0` (center)